# PHP upload and rename an uploaded file name according to the input file array

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

I would like to upload multiple images to my server using this code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="picture_01" name="userfile['01']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
<input id="picture_02" name="userfile['02']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
  <input id="picture_03" name="userfile['03']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
<input id="picture_04" name="userfile['04']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
<input id="picture_05" name="userfile['05']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
<input id="picture_06" name="userfile['06']" tabindex="auto" type="file">  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the upload_file.php

```
 <?php

$foldername = "anotherfolder";

$userfile = array(
            '01' => 'hello',
            '02' => 'bye',
            '03' => 'likka',
            '04' => 'pippa',
            '05' => 'laptop',
            '06' => 'cow06',
            '07' => 'cow07',
            '08' => 'cow08',
            '09' => 'cow09',
            '10' => 'cow10',            
            );

            echo $userfile ['01'];

foreach ($userfile as $keys => $values); 

//Upload Images
$success = 0;
$fail = 0;
$uploads_dir = "temp_images";
$count = 1;
foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$key];
        $uploadfile = "$uploads_dir/$name";
        $ext = strtolower(substr($uploadfile,strlen($uploadfile)-3,3));
        if (preg_match("/(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)/",$ext)){
            $newfile = "$uploads_dir/"."$values".".".$ext;
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newfile)){
                           }else{
                echo "Couldn't move file: Error Uploading the file. Retry after sometime.\n";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Extension.\n";
            $fail++;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I would like that when someone uploads the first picture in the first input it is renamed to 'hello', if it is uploaded in the second input it is renamed to 'bye'. If two pictures are uploaded the first picture is named 'hello' and the second picture renamed to 'bye'.

I tried to look for a solution but I wasn't successful. I can't understand what is wrong. The files are being named sequentially 'cow10' the latest value in the array regardless of which input the picture is uploaded from.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: A few things stand out to me. 1. You have a foreach loop for the $userfile and it's not actually a loop. Then you look through the errors as you should and reference that $values

Comment: Can you arrange my code with your solution please?

Answer (score 0):

A few things stand out to me. 1. You have a foreach loop for the $userfile and it's not actually a loop. Then you look through the errors as you should and reference that $values

The following was working for me sans a few issues with file permissions in the upload folder. The catch was that you weren't properly referencing the $userfile array AND the $_FILES object indexes were actually: '01' versus 01 on the $userfile array.

```
<?php

$foldername = "/var/www/vhosts/application/tmp"; // <-- Unused

$userfile = array(
            '01' => 'hello',
            '02' => 'bye',
            '03' => 'likka',
            '04' => 'pippa',
            '05' => 'laptop',
            '06' => 'cow06',
            '07' => 'cow07',
            '08' => 'cow08',
            '09' => 'cow09',
            '10' => 'cow10',
            );


//Upload Images
$success = 0;
$fail = 0;
$uploads_dir = "temp_images";
$count = 1;
foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {

        $file_key =  str_replace("'",'',$key);
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$key];

        $uploadfile = "$uploads_dir/$name";
        $ext = strtolower(substr($uploadfile,strlen($uploadfile)-3,3));
        if (preg_match("/(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg)/",$ext)){
            $newfile = $uploads_dir."/".$userfile[$file_key].".".$ext;
            echo "Copying ".$tmp_name." to ".$newfile;
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newfile)){
                           }else{
                echo "Couldn't move file: Error Uploading the file. Retry after sometime.\n";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Extension.\n";
            $fail++;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Here was my output when submitting 3 images.

> Copying /tmp/phpBttoCX to temp_images/hello.jpg
>
> Copying /tmp/phpFCHlLK to temp_images/bye.jpg
>
> Copying /tmp/phpi5u51x to temp_images/likka.jpg

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. When I tried it all uploaded filenames are being called ''hello.gif' or 'hello.jpg'. Further to your edit. I wish that if the user chooses to upload it from the 4th Input it is called - pippa, if from the 7th input 'cow'07.

Answer (score 0):

My code is working, you have to change it according to your requirements. I uploaded 2 .jpg files for testing and it saved as 1.jpg and 2 pictures .jpg. I don't complete my code as it's not my task to complete but to help you. Below is code of file **testing.php** (it's uploaded to same file where is this form. I updated code. It's working on my computer. You should try to solve such problems yourself.

```
<?php

$array = array("'01'"=>"1.jpg","'02'"=>"2.jpg");
$i=0;
if(!empty($_FILES["userfile"]["error"])){
    foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $array[$key];echo $key;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $name);
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="testing.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="picture_01" name="userfile['01']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
<input id="picture_02" name="userfile['02']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
  <input id="picture_03" name="userfile['03']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
<input id="picture_04" name="userfile['04']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
<input id="picture_05" name="userfile['05']" tabindex="auto" type="file">
<input id="picture_06" name="userfile['06']" tabindex="auto" type="file">  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't work. If you upload the image from the 2nd input i.e. picture_02 its renamed to 1.jpg and not 2.jpg

Comment: Now it's according to your needs. Hope it will help you. Note, it's `$array = array("'01'"=>"1.jpg","'02'"=>"2.jpg"); `Bye

Comment: I am getting the following error HP Warning:  move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Filename cannot be empty in ... on line 8

Comment: You have to solve such problems yourself. My array contains only 2 values, I think you are uploading more than 2 index. Please populate full array and try it. My code is example to help you, not working code.

Comment: I tried it only with one value... I think the problem may be in         $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];

Comment: Nevermind it didn't work. Thanks for your kind help.